# Page numbering at wrong place

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am quite new to TeX. I'm writing my thesis and I want to place the page numbers at bottom left for even pages and bottom right for odd pages. I've done this and it works for even pages, but the odd ones have the page number at the center. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry, amsmath, float, fancyhdr, standalone}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

Comment: `fancy` style is not applied to the first page, I suppose. Does the problem disappears if you put `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother` in the preamble?

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you! Can you explain how your command works? I don't understand it at all. `fancy` is not applied to the first page, why are you asking?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First pages of chapters, table of contents, and other "special" pages are defined to have a `plain` page style (`\thispagestyle{plain}` can be found in the definition of `\chapter` and so in `\tableofcontents`, etc.).

Even when you apply the `fancy` page style through the `fancyhdr` package, these pages continue to have the `plain` style.

So, if you want these pages to have the `fancy` style, you have to redefine the `plain` style to be the same of the `fancy` one:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy % plain style = fancy style
\makeatother
```

The same can be achieved with

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

I also suggest you to add the following line

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
```

to remove the header rule, since you are putting nothing in the header.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry, amsmath, float, fancyhdr, standalone}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy % plain style = fancy style
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\blinddocument % just for the example
\end{document}
```

Output (first two pages):

[image]

### EDIT

If you want to keep the header line in all pages but `plain` ones, forget what I said and simply put the line

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

in the preamble.

In this way you are redefining the `plain` style to be the same of `fancy` except for the header rule.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry, amsmath, float, fancyhdr, standalone}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\blinddocument % just for the example
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will accept your answer. Just one more question: What if I want to keep the header rule at all pages, except the first page of each chapter?

Comment: @Ellie See the edited answer.

Comment: Nice, it works! But still, if I have a header I don't want it to appear on the first page of each chapter, but just where the header rule is. If I change its style to `plain`, everything is messed uo again. But `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}` is not enough for this, right?

Comment: @Ellie In this case use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyhead{}}`

Comment: Just found it out! Thank you very much for your help!